# export segmented image with OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I need to export images (in a common format e.g. png, jpg, pdf, tiff) containing the original image showing the contour of the segmented objects.

So, I can segment a set of images using openCV and am able to draw the contours of the retrieved objects (in green) and, eventually, print the image together with the contours:

```
[...]

h, w = thresholded.shape[:2]
_, contours0, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresholded.copy(), cv.RETR_CCOMP, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = [cv.approxPolyDP(cnt, 3, True) for cnt in contours0]

[...]

cv.drawContours(origImage, [cnt], -1, (128, 255, 0), 2)
cv.circle(origImage, (cX, cY), 1, (255,0,0), -1)

[...]

#here it shows the image together with the found contours
#print a window with "f = filename" as main title
cv.namedWindow(f)
cv.imshow(f, origImage)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now I would like to export the image (origImage) together with its green-line delimited objects:

```
cv.imwrite(saveIn + dirn.split(directory)[1] + "/" + name + '.jpg', origImage)
```

but what I get is the same image I am providing as input. Basically there is no contour, in the exported image.

Am I missing some parameters?

EDIT:

The script requires 3 inputs which are:

- the absolute path pointing to the images
- the absolute path in which results (comprising a table with some
  features and the segmented images) will be stored
- the threshold

Comment: could it be that it is being saved in another place? or the path do not exist? try saving it first in an absolute path like `/home/user/debugImages/a.jpg` and see if it is the same...

Comment: I already am using absolute paths (I also export a table containing some features). I can see the exported images but no contour. Anyway, I am trying and I also edited the question to add these information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, my bad! **The code works**.

The problem is that I used a threshold which was too low for detecting any contour (event though it was detecting something too small to be shown) so, basically, there was nothing to show (it is a little bit trickier that but this is the point).